# The sound controls and function are finicky

Tags: audio, headphones

I just purchased my Macbook pro. It's a 13in, Mid 2012 running OS X yosemite.

The first time I used headphones, the sound completely cuts out. I unplugged the headphones and the sound had stopped working on my regular speakers as well. I went to system preferences and did something in the sound menu and the sound came back on. But then the controls stopped working, and I couldn't adjust the volume, or mute.

I'm not that computer savvy, but I'm not new, so I turned it off and then on again, it fixed the issue temporarily. Now if my computer goes to sleep and I wake it up, the sound doesn't work, I have to close the program, and start over. Everytime I've used headphones, I can get the sound to work after messing with the options in sound preferences. However with headphones in, no matter what I try, I can never adjust the volume or mute.

I never had an issue on my previous macbook, which is why I bought another when it was time to upgrade.

Comment: "I went to system preferences and did something" What exactly did you do? Could you explain what the temporary fix was?

Comment: You probably have a audio plug in installed so it changes the output device to headphones or speaker. Can you tell us what devices you have listed in the Sound Pref Pane -> Devices. As for not being able to change volume, try resetting your [PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063)